# Bash string matching

Tags: bash

I need a single line bash command that takes a piped input and returns true or false depending if it match a string or not..

This seems to work for the true or false part:

```
test `expr match "Release:11.04" "Release:11.04"` = 13 && echo true || echo false
```

But I cannot get  it to work properly with the other command's output..

What I need would be something like this:

```
test `expr match "`lsb_release -r`" "Release:11.04"` = 13 && echo true || echo false
```

So I tried with xargs, but I can't get it to work:

```
lsb_release -r | xargs -I {} test `expr {} "Release: 11.04"` = 13 && echo True || echo False
```

Also, if any of you happens to know a shorter way to achieve this, it would be greatly welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the $(cmd) syntax.

```
test $(expr match "$(lsb_release -r)" "Release:11.04") = 13 && echo true || echo false
```

Though on my system there is a tab in the output of lsb_release after ':', so you may want to doublecheck your checks.

And actually after fiddling a bit, I think this would be a nicer way with bash (tested on Debian system):

```
[[ "$(lsb_release -r)" =~ $'Release:\t6.0.2' ]] && echo true || echo false
```

Comment: Or more portably `[ "$(lsb_release -r | cut -f2)" = 6.0.2 ] && echo true || echo false`

Answer (score 1):

Why not this way:

```
[ `lsb_release -r | awk '{print $2}'` = "11.04" ] && echo true || echo false
```

BTW, if you need to use nested ``` `` ``` you can escape inner one with `\` like that:

```
test `expr match "\`lsb_release -r\`" "Release:11.04"`
```

But it looks ugly. Using $() is more readable, but bit less portable.

Answer (score 0):

This would be another simpler approach -

```
lsb_release -r | grep -q "11.04" && echo true || echo false
```

Basically, this greps the output of `lsb_release -r` for 11.04. `-q` in grep will return exit status zero if a match is found, which will echo `true`. `false` otherwise.

Comment: You don't need to look at grep's output, just use its exit status: `lsb_release -r | grep -q "11.04" && echo true || echo false`